# Qt - Storing a widget pointer in a QAction?

Tags: c++, qt

in Qt I have a table where each row has a button in one of the columns and that button opens a drop-down menu where you can click the actions. I connect the `triggered()` signal of the actions to a slot that will handle them, however in the slot I have to know for which row the action was triggered. I can't store it in `setData()`, because that only stores a `QVariant`. How else can I store a pointer to a widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QPushButton *)
```

...

```
QPushButton *pb = new QPushButton;
QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(pb);
qDebug() << pb << v.value < QPushButton * >();
```

Works to me.

Comment: is Q_DECLARE_METATYPE nessecary? So I have to use that macro with the type I want to store?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE : `This macro makes the type Type known to QMetaType as long as it provides a public default constructor, a public copy constructor and a public destructor. It is needed to use the type Type as a custom type in QVariant.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`QVariant::fromValue()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#fromValue) method for setting data.

If u need to determine signal's sender use

```
QWidget *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(sender());
```